# How do I get rid of creeping jenny

Tags: invasive

Thought creeping jenny was pretty until it became invasive. How do I get rid of it now.  When I pull it out the roots go forever and it just comes back.  PNW

Comment: Where is it growing now? Like, is it in your lawn or beds, or both?

Comment: Also, it appears that "creeping jenny" is used to refer to either Moneywort or Field Bindweed - do you know which one you're asking about?

Answer (score 1):

Spray with glyphosate. Follow the instructions. Repeat as necessary.

Comment: If it's field bindweed, glyphosate will knock it back but won't kill it.

Comment: @Jurp - Yes, it will. Follow the instructions. Repeat as necessary.

Comment: Peter - Once established, bindweed roots can grow up to 9 feet deep. RoundUp and 2,4-D will knock it back but will not kill it. If the bindweed is in lawn, the gardener can try 2,4-D/Dicamba at least twice a year. If it's in a garden, then constant pulling of new growth is probably best, so as not to kill nearby garden plants via drift.  See: https://www.maine.gov/dacf/php/gotpests/weeds/factsheets/morning-glory-cal.pdf for more info.